# ERC20 transaction list with API

Tags: php, blockchain, ethereum, erc20

I want to create ERC20 token, and I need callbacks, but blockchain does not support callback's.
So I need to connect with API and get all transactions.

Example token:
https://etherscan.io/token/0x259153f56e7cab5c2c31575adae5e9da8ee68e69When (I want to get all transaction IDs from this token)

Here is API documentation: https://etherscan.io/apis
But I can't find it, how it is possible.

Comment: Hi. can you elaborate on what exactly is the question? is it on the callback or is it on the transaction api not working ?

Comment: @VindhyaG Hi, callback does not supported at blockchain solidity code. So there is only one way, connect to blockchain with API and get transaction IDs. example url: https://bscscan.com/token/0x041dc554c22cbe213df61b3507c98a4a060a0e15 here are 19 transaction and I want all them "TXN HASH"

Comment: so if  i understand correctly you need to know how to get all transactions from a token called "TXN HASH"?

Comment: Thank you. Already find solution via API: https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=TOKEN_XXXX&startblock=1&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=3&sort=desc&apikey=API_XXX Same is for ETH tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Already find solution via API: https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=TOKEN_XXXX&startblock=1&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=3&sort=desc&apikey=API_XXX

Same is for ETH.